# Autoload and namespace structure for projects with static library

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I am trying to define a namespace/autoload structure for multiple projects. Each project has a library. The consists classes which will be extended for each project. Here is the content of one project

- /project1

  - /lib

    - parentclass.php
    - autoloader.php
  - index.php
  - myclass.php

parentclass.php:

```
<?php 
class parentclass{

}
?>
```

myclass.php

```
<?php

class pr1_myclass extends parentclass{

}
```

In index.php i will define a global array with settings which will be used in the autoloader:

```
<?php

$settings = array(
    'dir' => __DIR__;
    'lib_dir' => 'project1_dir',
    'lib_namespace' => '??',
);
$project_prefix = 'pr1';
$GLOBALS['projectsAutoloadSettings'][$project_prefix] = $settings;
```

The autoloader will be something like this:

```
<?php
function my_autoloader($className){

    $parts = explode('_',$className);
    if(isset($GLOBALS['projectsAutoloadSettings'][$parts[0])){
        $settings = $GLOBALS['projectsAutoloadSettings'][$parts[0]];
        //I now have settings array for this project. From here i can include the right file:
        include($settings['dir'].'/'.$parts[1].'.php');
    }else{
        //Need to include library file. This is part of my problem. I dont know how to handle this
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoLoader');
```

This was the structure for 1 project. I have multiple projects. The /lib directory in each project is the same.

Now i need a namespace structure which will work in both 2 environments mentioned below, while only having to change the $settings.

- Local developer environment. Here a single /lib should be used for all projects. So for example a class from project 3 will extends a parent class from the library from project 1.
- Active environment. Here each class in a project extends the library from its project. So a class from project 3 will always extend a parent class from project 3.

Multiple projects can be active at a single web page. I figure i need namespaces for this, but my main question is that the /lib directory is always the same code (copy pasted). I want to keep it that way, as far as i know it is not possible to have a different namespace for /project3/lib than for project1/lib.

How can i still achieve my goal. I am interested in the code-structure, things like autoloader code (classname to filename) i will figure out myself.

EDIT: An edit with an example of a problem i am facing, which seems not clear if i look at the comments.

It is in live (not developer) mode. I have a second project with the same structure as project one, but instead with this class in /project2/someclass.php

```
<?php
class pr2_someclass extends parentclass{

}    
?>
```

Now this is my code for running both projects:

```
<?php
//project 1 start:
$myClass1 = new pr1_myclass();
//This loads pr1_myclass which is an extension from the parent class in project1/lib/parentclass.php.
//So far so good

//Project 2 start
$myClass2 = new pr2_someclass();
//Here the problem occurs. This class loads pr2_someclass, but it will be an extension of project1/lib/parentclass.php instead of project2/lib/parentclass.php.
?>
```

Since both lib directories are identical, you might think i just should use the same library for both projects. However, there can be more than a year between two projects so it might be possible that the two libraries are not exactly identical.

Comment: Why not use one lib folder for all projects, the autoloader also receives the namespace, wich you can use to determine wich folder to look in.

Comment: That is the case in the developers mode. In the live mode however, it might be possible that the library has a few changes per project. For example, when there is a large amount of time between the two projects.

Comment: Just use the namespace to determine wich folder to look in.
Or make a define, if its development mode. If its true, look in these folder else, look in the others. Thats how we handle these kind of things at work

Comment: @RFLdev  How would that work when first project one is called, and then a parent class from the library in project 2, since that parent class might already be loaded by project 1.

Comment: If its allready loaded, autoloader dont need to search for it :)

Comment: @RFLdev Yes, but that means it extends from a parent class in project 1, and not from project 2 like it is supposed to.

Comment: Again, you can use defines to specify if its in development mode, and wich project is currently loaded. These constants you defined can be used in the autoloader to load the right classes. But do these projects use each other? does project 1 use project 2 and 3?

Comment: @RFLdev I am not sure if you understand the problem correctly. In not dev mode: Project 1 should use classes from library 1, and project 2 should use classes from library 2. However, the libraries are mostly identical, meaning the classes in there have the same name. Also, multiple projects can be loaded at the same page.

Comment: Namespacing should fix that issue. You can use the same classes within different folders with namespacing. You can use AS to give same classes different names. And from there you can use them as normal classes.

Comment: @RFLdev So how would you suggest that? Note that files in both libraries are almost the same, so they will have the same namespace.

Comment: No, they shouldn have the same namespace. Keep it seperate, they are located in different project folders, so dont give the same namespace to them. 
Just give each project a own namespace, and your problem is gone.

Comment: @RFLdev Yes, and then i would not post this question. The problem is, the files in the library are the same. Right now my 'solution' is to use a script to change the namespaces in each file before going live. I am looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: it doesnt matter if the files are the same. You can have 99 files that are identical, as long as they are in their own namespace....

Comment: @RFLdev
I know. The problem is that they should be the same. I am looking for a solution where they can be. You simple don't know the answer to this. Everything you suggest is something which i currently am doing/already have considered, but i am looking for a better solution.